# Spring bean validation won't replace message for typeMismatch errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I've created a custom `MessageInterpolator` for my `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` but for some reason no **`typeMismatch`** errors are getting passed into it. All the other validators I'm using  like `@NotNull`, `@Size`, `@Pattern`, etc. show up as expected.

I'm left with a really ugly error that I can't show to users:

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile' for property 'data'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] for property 'data': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"

**Clarification:** I am purposely sending a `String` instead of a file to trigger the `typeMismatch` error. My goal is to gracefully handle this kind of validation error with a human-friendly error message instead of the exception text.

**Relevant version information:**

- validation-api 1.0.0.GA
- hibernate-validator 4.3.0.Final
- spring-* 3.1.1.RELEASE

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with `Multipart` arguments, I suspect that you are implementing file upload. Have you configured a [multipartResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart)?

> By default, Spring does no multipart handling [...]. You enable Spring multipart handling by adding a multipart resolver to the web application's context.

Note that the configuration differs if you are using Apache Commons or Servlet 3.0.

Other possible causes:

- The request does not contain a multipart (no file is sent)
- The request uri is wrong (it was intended for some other handler method)

Comment: Yes, I have the `multipartResolver`. I apologize for not being clear that I actually have success receiving files. (I'll update the OP to note this.) I am purposely sending a String instead of a file to cause the `typeMismatch` validation error. My goal is to handle the error gracefully. The error shows up in the `BindingResult` object and shows all the possible codes, but they aren't getting mapped to the proper message.